# RX to react to separate triggers but then treat the action synchronously

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming, masstransit

I'm writing a service that basically synchronizes 2 datasources.  The requirements are that it syncs periodically, but it's also possible for an admin to manually trigger it to sync in response to certain cases.

We're using MassTransit messages for IPC, so the web interface will send a (say) TriggerSyncMessage via MassTransit and the Service will see these.

Then using reactive extensions we subscribe to the MT message, and we set up a timer observable to react to as well - excellent.

But then, because these observables are of different types, we can't Merge() them.
We want both (re)actions to trigger the same thing (the syncing stuff), so i'm currently using a Subject to tie the 2 observables together, and I then subscribe on that for the final part.

Like so :

```
var syncMessageObserver = Bus.Instance.AsObservable<TriggerSyncMessage>();

var subject = new Subject<string>();

syncMessageObserver.Subscribe(msg =>
{
    subject.OnNext("from message");
});

var timerSyncer = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60000)).Timestamp();

 timerSyncer.Subscribe(x =>
{
    subject.OnNext("from timer");
});

subject.AsObservable().Subscribe(msg =>
{
    // actual syncing stuff
});
```

I have 2 questions on this approach :
1. Is this.... the correct way to handle this case?  I'm not sure if you're meant to use a subject to tie observables together, or if there's a better way.

1. As an extension to this problem, i would prefer the next run of the sync method not start until the current one has completed.  Also multiple calls to start the sync are considered only once when it is time to sync.
   So if we have the sync operation running from the timer, and the impatient admin presses the "sync" button 5 times, when the timer operation completes we only run one more time after that.
   Any suggestions on how to approach that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part looks fairly solvable. Just ignore the values and project your message. Here we use the pattern of naming an ignored parameter '_' (which is a valid C# variable name).

```
//TODO: Rename syncMessageObserver. It is not an Observer, it is an Observable.
Observable.Merge(
    syncMessageObserver.Select(_ => "from message"),
    Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60000)).Timestamp().Select( _=> "from timer")
)
.Subscribe(msg =>
{
    // actual syncing stuff
});
```

The next problem is a little but more difficult, but is a common one. Often there requirements are for different reasons, but here you can still use the same solution, and that would be the `ObserveLatestOn` operator. This came out of the Banks, where we need to only display the latest price. If, in the time it took to render a price, many other prices had been received, we should only show the latest one.

You can see it discussed [on the MSDN Rx forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bbcc1af9-64b4-456b-9038-a540cb5f5de5/how-do-i-ignore-allexceptthelatest-value-when-my-subscribe-method-is-running), at [JamesWorld's blog](http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=192) and [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tp5mRlHwZ7M) discussing the background to how this came about.

You would simply update your query to have the new operator and pass in the appropriate scheduler.

```
//TODO: Rename syncMessageObserver. It is not an Observer, it is an Observable.
Observable.Merge(
    syncMessageObserver.Select(_=>"from message"),
    Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60000)).Timestamp().Select(_=>"from timer")
)
.ObserveLatestOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
.Subscribe(msg =>
{
    // actual syncing stuff
});
```

For more information on what a Scheduler is and how to choose the appropriate one for you scenario, see [here](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html). If Testing is important to you, then you will also need to look [here](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html) for content on how to unit test scheduled/concurrent code in a fast and deterministic manner.

Comment: Works perfectly, thankyou.  And thanks also for introtorx.com Lee - I refer to it a lot :)

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more, this one is definitely going into Evernote for reference. Also, thanks for the book - interesting read and like Spiffeah, referenced a lot :-)